# How I can select object by name with JMESPath?

Tags: ansible, jmespath

How to extract an element from JSON file by element name? For example what I have in the ansible-playbook:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ test }}"
```

This is output (my file)

```json
ok: [test] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "element1": {
                "test1": "test3",
                "test2": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ],
                "info": {
                    "test4": "test",
                    "test": 1,
                    "test": "test"
                },
                "test": "test",
                "test": "test",
                "test": "test",
                "test": "test"
            },
            "element2": {
                "test": "test",
                "test": [
                    "test",
                    "test"
                ],
                "test": {
                    "test": "test",
                    "test": 1,
                    "test": "test",
                    "test": 1
                },
                "test": "test",
                "test": "test",
                "test": "test",
                "test": "test"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to create a filter to get only `element1` by his name

```yaml
- name: Get item by name
  debug: msg="{{ my_json_file | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
  vars:
    jmesquery: "[?contains(@, `element2`)]"
```

And expect to get output like

```json
"element1": {
    "test1": "test3",
    "test2": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    ],
    "info": {
        "test4": "test",
        "test": 1,
        "test": "test"
    },
    "test": "test",
    "test": "test",
    "test": "test",
    "test": "test"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In JMESPath, basic querying of an element based on a key is as simple as specifying the key, see [basic querying](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#basic-expressions).

So, in your case, the correct JMESPath query would simply be:

```
[].element2
```

And, so, in your task:

```yaml
 - name: Get item by name
   debug: 
     msg: "{{ my_json_file | json_query(jmesquery) }}"
   vars:
     jmesquery: "[].element2"
```

---

This said, Ansible is based on YAML, which is a superset of JSON, so your task can as well be achieved in a way easier manner:

```yaml
 - name: Get item by name
   debug: 
     msg: "{{ my_json_file.0.element2 }}"
```